# How to download name and images on one row in ascending order

Tags: swift2, ios9

I have researched this and nothing seems to be working. I am trying to build a recipe app and the the image of the dish & names of the dish (appetizer) are not downloading in order.  How can I do this?

Code:

```
class Appetizers: UITableViewController {

    var valueToPass: String!
    var valuePassed: String!
    var appetizer = [String]()
    
    var images = [UIImage]()
    
    
    func refresh() {
        
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            
        })
        
    }
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Parse - class - column
        let query = PFQuery(className: "Appetizers")
        query.orderByAscending("appetizer")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        
            if error == nil {
                
                if let objects = objects {
                    
                    for object in objects {
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        let load = object.objectForKey("appetizer") as! String
                        self.appetizer.append(load)
                        
                        let imageFile = object["imageFiles"] as! PFFile
                        imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                            
                            if error != nil {
                                
                                print(error)
                                
                            } else {
                                
                                if let data = imageData {
                                    
                                    self.images.append(UIImage(data: data)!)
                                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                                    
                                }
                                
                            }
                        })
                        
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                
            } else {
                
                print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
                
            }
        }
        
        sleep(1)
        refresh()
    }
    
    
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return appetizer.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = appetizer[indexPath.row]
        
        // add image to table
        if images.count > indexPath.row {
            
            cell.imageView?.image = images[indexPath.row]
            
        }

        return cell
    }
    
    
    // when user taps on cell ...
    
    func getCellLabel () {
        
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell!
        
        valueToPass = currentCell.textLabel!.text
        
    }
    
    
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        
        getCellLabel()
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("0", sender: self)
        
    }


}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but never `sleep` in main thread. And you don't need to call `reloadData` from `viewDidLoad`. Your asynchronous queries are reloading the table when appropriate, so those two last lines of `viewDidLoad` should be removed.

Comment: I find without the sleep(), the table won't load. and i get an error in my output:  *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.30.14/UITableView.m:1426

Comment: Then let's solve that problem. But inserting `sleep` is just addressing a symptom rather than the problem. Blocking the main thread with `sleep` is never going to be the right solution. lol. Take out both `sleep` and `refresh` out of `viewDidLoad` and if you really get an error, then show us the complete error message.

Comment: I have a directory, when i select "Appetizers" from the list after removing sleep() and refresh(), i get this error on Xcode's output screen: 2016-04-17 23:31:50.381 Great Recipes[1812:1803747] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.30.14/UITableView.m:1426

Comment: Usually there's a more after this part. Is there nothing else on the console after that?

Comment: No. Thats it. If i allow sleep then that goes away but i know its a problem :/

Comment: If you search stack overflow for `_endCellAnimationsWithContext`, there are a ton of questions, so I'd suggest you look at those. If you don't see an answer there, create [the simplest possible reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that manifests this behavior and post that as a new question.

Comment: @Rob - what about begin and end updates?  I've been reading about them but as being a beginner in iOS programming, i am not sure where to put them or what to put in them.

Comment: You often don't need to do begin and end updates. It's only necessary when you doing multiple updates in one iteration of the runloop. But where you need begin/end updates, but they (a) need to be balanced; and (b) must be coordinated with updates to the underlying model that the `UITableViewDataSource` methods reference.

Comment: i have no idea then what the problem is.  It says to use begin and end updates if inserting, deleting or selecting.  The user would select a row to view the recipe and when i select the row "appetizers", the error appears.

Comment: I like to create a minimalist example that reproduces the problem. You can do this in one of two ways, either make copy your project and slowly prune all the irrelevant stuff (including Parse queries and/or network requests) until you get to a point that you identify precisely what is causing the problem. Or, I often approach it from the other direction, start with a blank project and then slowly add stuff like you have in your app, until you can reproduce the problem. Not only does that help you create MCVE for posting here, but often you end up identifying the source of the problem yourself.

Comment: Re `begin`/`endUpdates`, it doesn't say to do this if inserting/deleting, but it only says that you do this if you're doing a _series_ of insert/deletes (i.e. multiple ones), but want to animate them all together (or, in other words, if you want to defer the call to the `UITableViewDataSource` methods until when you call `endUpdates`). And you certainly don't use these when merely selecting a cell. Only when doing changes that require a re-calling of the `UITableViewDataSource` methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When performing asynchronous queries, you have no assurances regarding the order they complete. So, the concept of two separate arrays, one an array of strings and another an array of images will always be problematic.

You could, for example, replace `images` with a dictionary indexed by the appetizer name, and thus it wouldn't matter what order they complete.

```
var appetizer = [String]()
var images = [String: UIImage]()
```

Thus, it might look like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let query = PFQuery(className: "Appetizers")
    query.orderByAscending("appetizer")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { objects, error in
        guard error == nil, let objects = objects else {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        for (index, object) in objects.enumerate() {
            let appetizerName = object.objectForKey("appetizer") as! String
            self.appetizer.append(appetizerName)

            let imageFile = object["imageFiles"] as! PFFile
            imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { imageData, error in
                guard error == nil, let data = imageData else {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }

                // when the image comes in, asynchronously update only that one row

                self.images[appetizerName] = UIImage(data: data)
                self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            }
        }

        // reload the table only once, after all of the `appetizer` entries are created (but likely before the images come in)

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

And

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let name = appetizer[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = name
    cell.imageView?.image = images[name]

    return cell
}
```

Or you could just replace these two separate properties with one that is an array of custom objects (e.g. an `Appetizer` object that has both a `name` property and an `image` property).

But any way you do that, you want to name sure you're not dealing with two separate array.

---

By the way, but this process of loading all of the images can be problematic if you have a lot of rows. This code is employing "eager" loading of images (loading them whether they're currently required or not). The problem is that images are relatively large assets (in comparison to the string values) and you can run into memory issues, network bandwidth issues, etc.

One generally likes to employ "lazy" loading (e.g. let `cellForRowAtIndexPath` request the image only when it's needed. For example, let's say you have 200 rows, of which only 12 are visible at one point. You shouldn't be requesting 200 images, but rather only that for the 12 visible ones. If you take the image retrieval out of `viewDidLoad` and, instead, have `cellForRowAtIndexPath` request them one at a time, you'll have much better network performance and less demanding memory characteristics.

If you're going to save the images in some structure like the code currently does, at the very least make sure you purge those images upon receiving notification of a memory warning (and, obviously, gracefully handle the re-requesting them in a JIT manner as needed).

Comment: thanks for answering so quickly @Rob.  If i change images to what you recommended, i get two errors in my code: 1.  self.images.append(UIImage(data: data)!) -> Value of type '(String: UIImage)' has no member 'append' and 2. self.images.append(UIImage(data: data)!) -> Cannot subscript a value of type '(String: UIImage)' with an index of type 'int'.  One other thing, my imageFiles column in parse is of type file - is that correct?

Comment: Yep, if you change it to a dictionary, you're not appending to an array any more, but rather doing `images[appetizerName] = image`. See code sample. Re `imageFiles` being `PFFile`, I assume it is or else that forced cast would crash.

Comment: @LizG - BTW, unrelated to the question at hand, I've added a caveat about the memory handling of this process of requesting all of the images up front. Generally we like to employ "lazy" loading, instead, and make sure to purge any caches upon memory pressure.

Comment: excuse my ignorance, but what do you mean by the last post?  If you could dummy down what you just said, i would appreciate it.

Comment: @LizG - Bottom line, if there are a lot of images involved, you don't want to retrieve them until they're required by the user interface (i.e. those rows are visible). This is what is meant by "lazy" loading of images. So, if you have 100 images, but can only see 12 at a time, you should only retrieve those 12, not all 100. And when the user scrolls to 13th image, then just retrieve that 13th image, just in time. Now, if you only have a max of a dozen images, maybe this isn't an issue in your case. But if you can have many images, this "lazy" image loading is the way to go.

Comment: Got it all worked out!  Check out my answer and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem with my table not loading without sleep() ...
I had 'self.tableView.reloadData()' outside of the block.
Rob was very helpful :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I should have mentioned that. If you look at my code snippet, I moved it inside the block, too. lol.